# Correct way to reference image from asset folder in a Markdown document (that works both rendered locally and via Jekyll)?

Tags: image, visual-studio-code, jekyll

What is the correct way, in a Markdown document, to reference images that are stored in the `/asset` folder, so they can be rendered locally (Visual Studio Code) but also deployed in a Jekyll site?

Right now I include my images like this:

`![alt text]({{ site.url }}/assets/image.png)`

This works only when the site is rendered with Jekyll and if `site.url` is correctly set, which means that `_config.yml` has to be changed depending on the location the Jekyll project is deployed (on root of domain vs. in subfolder).

But this does **not** work at all if I render the document in e.g. Visual Studio Code. There I haev this option:

`![alt text](/assets/image.png)`

which will of course not work when deployed with Jekyll in a subfolder.

Or I can use a fully relative reference:

`![alt text](../assets/image.png)`

which is very impractical as image paths depend on where I have my content files. Moving a file from one folder to another changes the image URL.

Is there a way to make both Jekyl and local rendering (e.g. Visual Studio Code) work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following way misses the `baseurl`, i.e. it doesn't handle subdirectories:

```
 ![alt text]({{ site.url }}/assets/image.png)
```

To fix that, have `baseurl` in `_config.yml` and use it in your links:

```
![alt text]({{ site.url }}/{{site.baseurl}}/assets/image.png)
```

Even better, use `absolute_url` that will include `url` and `baseurl` generating full paths:

```
![alt text]({{"/assets/image.png" | absolute_url}})
```

## Update

As discussed in comments, the above solution won't work in VSCode but having images with relative paths does.

So putting the mages in each post/collection folder and loading them with relative paths should make VSCode able to render images in each file - while also keeping Jekyll happy and render the image as it should.

Comment: Good first point, I think I abused `site.url` until now to include the `baseurl`.

Comment: `absolute_url` though doesn't solve my real problem though, as VS Code (and all non-Jekyll renderer) has (/have) no idea what to do with it. Shame.

Comment: Works for me in **Emacs**. From what you said, it seems that it works without a baseurl in VS, then you can have a separate `_config.yml` for development that just sets an empty `baseurl` so your editor can render it. Having many config files can be done with `--config` or directly set the parameter `--baseurl` at command line.

Comment: As I understand it VS Code doesn't know and care about any of that. It only renders plain .md files into a default template. Images are rendered with absolute path as project dir and relative to current file.

Comment: What if you put the mages in each post folder and loads it with a relative path.

Comment: For posts that might work (good idea!), but I have `articles` which is a collection, adding an `_articles` folder in the mix. --- Actually, let me try that - I don't know what Jekyll does with assets in a collections folder --- Yay, it works! As I said before relative images work in VS Code, now I learned that an `assets` folder in `_collections` is applied onto the main `assets` folder in `_site` - so Jekyll rendering also works. It even makes more sense anyway to keep the images with the articles! Can you create that as a separate answer so I can accept it?